# 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter' problem arises even when layout parameter is set

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, swift4

You can see from the code below that layout parameter has been set inside `ViewDidLoad()`, but it gives me an error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be
>   initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'

```
var layer: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {

        var item = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        item.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)

        return item

    }()
```

`UICollectionView` object has been set in property initializer because obviously I want this `UICollectionView` object to be accessible globally:

```
var dataCollectionViews = UICollectionView()

viewDidLoad(){

dataCollectionViews = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0) , collectionViewLayout: self.layer)

        view.addSubview(dataCollectionViews)

        self.dataCollectionViews.delegate = self
        self.dataCollectionViews.dataSource = self
        self.dataCollectionViews.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: collectionViewReuse)
        self.dataCollectionViews.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.dataCollectionViews.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.dataCollectionViews.isHidden = true

  changed()
}
```

When I moved contents inside `changed()` to inside of `viewDidLoad()` and initialized dataCollectionViews inside of `viewDidLoad()`, everything worked as intended, showing `UICollectionView` object when selecting first button of segmented Control.

```
@objc func changed() {

    if segmentTime.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

        self.dataCollectionViews.isHidden = false

        let dataCollectionTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.dataCollectionViews, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: sortLabel, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10)

        let dataCollectionLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.dataCollectionViews, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10)

        let dataCollectionRight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.dataCollectionViews, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -10)

        let dataCollectionHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.dataCollectionViews, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .height, multiplier: 520/812, constant: 0)

        let dataCollectionWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.dataCollectionViews, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .width, multiplier: 355/375, constant: 0)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([dataCollectionLeft, dataCollectionRight, dataCollectionHeight, dataCollectionWidth, dataCollectionTop])

    }

    if segmentTime.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {



    }

    if segmentTime.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {



    }

}
```

I'd love to try to set dataCollectionViews object in property initializer but I know it is not possible, but it seems like `dataCollectionViews` needs be initialized with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout()` on first try. What other alternative is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
private lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 188.0, height: 268.0)

    let result: UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    result.register(CellClass.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    result.dataSource = self
    result.delegate = self
    return result
}()
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.